# logstash tab separator not escaping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have tab separated data which I want to input into `logstash`. Here is my configuration file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/*.csv"
        type => "testSet"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => "\t"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

It simply looks for all `.csv` files and separates them using tabs. For an input like this:

```
col1    col2
data1    data2
```

`logstash` output is (for the two rows):

```
column1 => "col1\tcol2"
column1 => "data1\tdata2"
```

Obviously it is not correctly parsing it. I saw that this issue was brought up a while ago [here](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1550) but there was no solution. Does anyone know if this problem has been resolved or maybe there's another way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Instead of using "\t" as the seperator, input an actual tab.
like this:

```
filter {
   csv {
    separator => "  "
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Looking now, that's pretty obvious.

Comment: Well that deserves a comment in the config file: 
`separator => " " # <- this white space is actually a tab, don't change it, it's already perfect`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-separator

> Define the column separator value. If this is not specified, the default is a comma ,. If you want to define a tabulation as a separator, you need to set the value to the actual tab character and not \t.